# UWP messagebox mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I know there where many questions regarding how to open a MessageBox in UWP, but how do I open a MessageBox in MVVM?

After the User clicks A `<Button>` it fires a Command `Command="{Binding FireComand}"` in my VM it is handled like usual. In my case it adds an object to an `ObservableCollection`.

But I want my Users to get Feedback, that their Action worked/or not.

Is there an easy way to show a simple MessageBox "Done!" surrounded by a black Rectangle which closes after 2 sec?

EDIT:
What I want is something like this

[image]

Comment: Show a toast: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541923/how-to-create-informative-toast-notification-in-uwp-app

Comment: I thank you for the link - but the link does not answer my question for MVVM - I will edit my Question.

Comment: I have to correct myself. Toast is not what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss a `MessageDialog` by cancelling the task created when calling its `ShowAsync` method, take a look at [Programmatically dismiss a MessageDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222942/programmatically-dismiss-a-messagedialog)

Regarding MVVM, I abstracted dialogs into a service that I use in my ViewModels, take a look at https://github.com/igorkulman/Kulman.UWP/blob/master/Kulman.UWP/Services/DialogService.cs

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look in there. So  DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
        dt.Start();
    }
-> This Gets the Countdown, but how do I Close it from my VM?
    Sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: Another question: How do I implement your Code?